# Get all filenames from directory via PHP script

Tags: php, directory, scandir

Im using Angular 2+ for my project which is hosted on a ftp server. On entrance I want to load all filenames of a certain directory on my ftp server in an array and return it to Typescript. This is my code so far:

Folder structure:

```
-scripts
   - getMasterplan.php
-shared_plaene
```

TS:

```
    let http = new XMLHttpRequest()
    http.open('POST', Globals.PATH + '/scripts/getMasterplan.php', true)

    // http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    let resp
    http.onreadystatechange = ()=> {

        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200)
            resp = http.responseText

        console.log('resp',resp)
    }

    http.send(null)
```

PHP:

```
<?php

  session_start();

  $files = array();

  $rootDir = "../shared_plaene";

  $path = $rootDir;
  $files = scandir($path);

  echo $files;

?>
```

The `response` is `undefined` or `"Array"`

**SOLVED: You cannot echo an Array**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [PHP scandir function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

**Example**

```
<?php
$dir = "/images/";

// Sort in ascending order - this is default
$a = scandir($dir);

// Sort in descending order
$b = scandir($dir,1);

print_r($a);
//Array ( [0] => . [1] => ..  [2] => cat.gif  [3] => dog.gif  [4] => horse.gif   [5] => myimages )
echo ($a[4]);
// horse.gif

?>
```

You can't `echo` an `Array`. If you use `print_r` instead it will print it with the syntax as above